# link a button to a layout

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to link a button to another layout in eclipse. When I press the button, this function in MainActivity.java runs:

```
public void press(View v)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GolPooch.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

I have written this code in GolPooch.java:

```
    package com.example.chance;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;


public class GolPooch extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.golpooch_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

But it have run time error when I press the button! I have searched a lot but I found nothing. Why it does not work?

Comment: where you got an error?

Comment: post the error code or stack trace then only we can help.

Comment: So you basically onClick() of that button you want the button activity's layout to be changed? Because on your intent you leave the activity context completely.

Comment: Which error you have got??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have  to write

```
  Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GolPooch.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

and define your GolPooch.java class in your manifest file.

```
  <activity android:name=".GolPooch" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the issue.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GolPooch1.class);
```

Here you are calling a class named `GolPooch1` but the file which you created is `GolPooch.java` So there is a mismatch and it fails.

**Second Option:**

Did you define the new activity in manifest? If not, define it first and then do a project clean and build.

Comment: @MeysamValuyan And what about the second option, did you add the second activity `GolPooch` in your manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".GolPooch" />
```